# Deleting saved objects from a class Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the most efficient way to delete an existing object from a Rails class? I have an array of objects

```
person_array = [Person1, Person2, Person3]
```

My goal is to delete all of the people in that array from a table in which they are members.

So I have a People class which they currently belong to.

I was thinking something like `People.delete(person_array)` which seems to be executing the proper SQL statements. How do I get those delete statements to actually change my People table though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the objects, you can just call [`destroy_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all) with them:

```
Person.destroy_all(:id => person_array)
```

Unlike [`delete_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete_all), this will invoke the model's callbacks, which may take longer, but preserves integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need to get the ids or Activerecord does that but for you.

```
Person.delete_all person_array.map(&:id)
```